# Proof that no number less than $b$ can be an upper bound.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

The following are definitions used in the two proofs given below:

Definition: A subset $I$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is called an interval if, for any $a,b \in I$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a \le x \le b$, we have $x \in I$.

Definition: Let $a \le b$ be any two real numbers. The open interval $(a,b)$ is defined as the set $$ (a,b) = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : a < x < b \}$$

The following proof is from a Calculus textbook:

> Let $a \leq b$ be any two real numbers. What is $\sup(a,b)$?

> Proof.
> If $x \in (a,b)$, then $a < x < b$. This immediately tells us that $a$ is a lower bound and $b$ is an upper bound. Any real number less than $b$ (but greater than $a$) is in the interval, so no number less than $b$ can be an upper bound. Therefore, $\sup(a,b) \geq b$. But $\sup(a,b) \leq b$ by definition (since $b$ is an upper bound), so $\sup(a,b)=b$.

If one tried to show "no number less than $b$ can be an upper bound," would that proof look like the following?

Proof.
Suppose $y \in \mathbb{R}$ is less than $b$ and greater than $a$. Then by definition, $y \in (a,b)$. This means that there are real numbers $a'$ and $b'$ in $(a,b)$ such that $a<a' \leq y \leq b' < b$ (where $b' < b$ since $b$ is an upper bound and $b \notin (a,b)$, and $a < a'$ since $a$ is a lower bound and $a \notin (a,b))$. If $y = b'$, then there exists $\dfrac{b' + b}{2} \in (a,b)$ where $y < \dfrac{b + b'}{2} < b$. In particular, $y=b'$ is not an upper bound of $(a,b)$ since $y < \dfrac{b + b'}{2}$. On the other hand, if $y < b'$, then $\dfrac{y + b'}{2} \in (a,b)$ where $y<\dfrac{y + b'}{2}<b'$. This implies that $y < b'$ is not an upper bound of $(a,b)$ since $y < \dfrac{y + b'}{2}$. Any $y \in \mathbb{R}$ less than or equal to $a$ would, by definition, be a lower bound. Thus, no real number less than $b$ can be an upper bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your argument is a little more complicated than it needs to be. We can say given $x\in(a,b)$, there exist a $y=\frac{x+b}{2}\in (a,b)$. This is because the average of x and b will always be between the two. Since there exists such a $y$ then $x$ is not an upper bound.

Comment: I thought about doing it that way at first, but I tried to work around the author's explanation since I thought that "any real number less than $b$ (but greater than $a$) is in the interval" was a little redundant if the explanation was used as a proof.